# Где найти свежую документацию по gnu c?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, c11

По запросу в Гугле - выдает страницу https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html в которой ничего не говориться о c 11, на официальном сайте я ничего подходящего не нашел.

Где можно найти актуальный мануал по gnu c 11?

Comment: а в документации действительно много чего можно [сказать о c11](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)? (я честно не в курсе, т.к. не программист)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Официально этот документ называется так:

INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ©ISO/IEC ISO/IEC9899:201x

Найти его можно, например, здесь:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf

Comment: Извините, но Вы ошибаетесь. В вопросе речь шла о GNU C, Вы же предоставили ссылку на стандарт (а точнее, его черновик) ISO C. Это первый момент. Второй: документ не может официально называться ISO/IEC 9899:201x - буква 'x' на конце как-раз и свидетельствует о том, что это черновик.

Comment: *но Вы ошибаетесь* - вполне может быть. Но ведь зная номер с буквой "х" можно легко найти этот документ и без буквы? Касательно GNU C - а какой тут может быть СТАНДАРТ?! Ведь GNU C - это расширение стандарта... И какая организация может утвердить СТАНДАРТ "гнутого" ПО ?!

Comment: Вы даете волю эмоциям. "какой тут может быть СТАНДАРТ" - в том то и дело, что никакого. На это я Вам и указал. Что касается меня - я не говорил ни о каких _стандартах_ в контексте GNU C - и это видно по моему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Прочтите, пожалуйста, вот [этот](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) документ.

Особое внимание обратите на данный абзац:

> By default, GCC provides some extensions to the C language that, on
>   rare occasions conflict with the C standard. See Extensions to the C
>   Language Family. Some features that are part of the C99 standard are
>   accepted as extensions in C90 mode, and some features that are part of
>   the C11 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 and C99 modes. Use
>   of the -std options listed above disables these extensions where they
>   conflict with the C standard version selected. You may also select an
>   extended version of the C language explicitly with -std=gnu90 (for C90
>   with GNU extensions), -std=gnu99 (for C99 with GNU extensions) or
>   -std=gnu11 (for C11 with GNU extensions).

Ссылку на описание *GNU C extensions* на всякий случай оставляю здесь: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html